# Can two irreducible polynomials have a common root?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I was reading proof of theorem which says

**Let f(x) ∈ F[x] be an irreducible polynomial.
If f'(x) $\neq$ 0 then f(x) is separable.**

Proof :

Suppose r is a multiple root of f(x). Then f'(r) = 0. Since f(x) is irreducible, f(x) | f'(x). But this is a contradiction since deg f'(x) < deg f(x). Therefore f(x) is separable.

My doubt is why f(x) | f'(x) and why deg f'(x) < deg f(x) cause a trouble because we didn't assume that f(x) is the minimal polynomial of r.

Comment: Any polynomial $f(x)$ irreducible in $F[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of any of its roots over $F$. And it's not possible for an irreducible polynomial to have a nonconstant divisor of strictly smaller degree.

Comment: @anon Ya I know this fact but can you  guide me the  proof of why this holds true?

Comment: If $f(x)$ has root $r\not\in F$ with minimal polynomial $m(x)$ over $F$ then $m(x)\mid f(x)$. If $f(x)$ is monic irreducible, then either $m(x)=1$ or $m(x)=f(x)$. Since $r\not\in F$, we know $m(x)\ne1$, so $m(x)=f(x)$. Handle the case $r\in F$ separately. Thus any irreducible polynomial is the minimal polynomial of its roots.

Comment: @anon I guess your proof is giving a cyclic argument to my question "Can to irreducible polynomials have same root ! " To be more precise $m(x)$and $f(x)$ have one common root ,what leads to implication$ m(x)∣f(x)$

Comment: $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $r$ and $f(r)=0$, that's why $m(x)\mid f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to go back to basics, and say that the gcd of $f$ and $f'$ has degree $\ge 1$, contradicting irreducibility.

They used instead the fact that if $f(x)$ is irreducible and $f$ and $g$ have a common root in some extension field then $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

As a mather of fact $f$ is the minimal polynomial as beeing irreductible and having $a$ as a root is equivalent to beeing the minimal polynomial of $a$.

You can prove this by suposing that there is a polynomial $g$, with $g \neq f$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ then $g(x)|f(x)$ but that is a contradiction to $f$ beeing irreductible.

The key fact is that the minimal polynomial divides any other polynomial with $a$ as a root comes from the algoritm of division as $f = hg + r$ with $r$ the remainder and by evaluating in $a$ we get $f(a) = h(a)g(a) +r(a) \implies r(a) = 0$ then $r$ would be a polynomial with smaller degree than $f$ with $a$ as a root.